# How to Convert Multi date format into one in R

Tags: r, date

I am running some data pre-processing in Rstudio. There are two different kinds of date format in my data.frame. And I want to convert the numeric in the DOB column into %Y/%m/%d format like others. Could you please offer me some advice? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: look into the lubridate package

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide information on what you have tried so far and what errors you are getting

Comment: You should make sure that you're not providing some sensitive data like personal information here.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about this. No, it is not. The data is from some virtual course and the provider stressed that all the data involved are for the exercise only and not real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nchar of that column will allow to distinguish the two different data formats. Then use the foramting to convert your date inputs into desired format.

This could be achieved using the tidyverse in one line

`library(tidyverse)`

`my.data.frame%>%mutate(Date_new=ifelse(nchar(as.character(DOB))<5, format(as.Date(.$DOB,  "%Y-%m-%d"), DOB)`